# VBA: Invalid Qualifier

Tags: excel, vba

My vba code should organiza a balance sheet I just pasted o Excel from a PDF. So, like most balance sheets, there are the description of the item (asset/liabilities/etc) and the values from the years that are being analyzed.

First, I was trying to identify in which position the text ended. So I wrote the following code, which is giving me and error (Invalid Qualifier).

```
Dim subjectCell As String
Dim letters As String
Dim index As Integer

letters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklçzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLÇZXCVBNM "
subjectCell = ActiveCell.Value

For i = 0 To Len(subjectCell) - 1

    If (letters.Contains(Mid(subjectCell, i + 1, 1))) Then
    Else
     index = i
Next i

Cell("A1").Value = index
```

Comment: `letters.Contains(...)` would work in VB.Net but not VBA which is a very different thing.  `InStr()` is how you would search for one string within another.  There is likely a more efficient way to do this but its unclear what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: You are also missing the `End If`... `If...Else...End If`

Comment: Thnx for the answer. I tried swapping the Contains for the InStr(), but I still got the same error. My main goal is to separate the text description and the number results in different side by side cells. This would repeat for each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()
    Dim subjectCell As String
    Dim letters As String
    Dim index As Integer

    letters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklçzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLÇZXCVBNM "
    subjectCell = ActiveCell.Value2

    For i = 1 To Len(subjectCell)
        If InStr(1, letters, Mid(subjectCell, i, 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            index = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    Range("A1").Value2 = index
End Sub
```

Comment: Thnx. I am still having an error regarding the last line of code.

Comment: Compilation Error: 'Sub' or 'Function' not defined.

Comment: Have you wrapped it in `Sub` tags?

Comment: Yep, I wapped Cell with Range and it compiled, but it is returning me the wrong value. It is returning the position of the last character in the string and not the last letter.

Comment: Can you give an example. e.g. String you're inputting, what you're expecting and what it is giving?

Comment: I solved. It was stupid of me. The index was being reassigned in the for loop. I exited it once if was true. Thanx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here

1. No end if for your if statement
2. Your cell should be `range` if you're defining a range like A1, cells is for 1, 1 type reference
3. Using ActiveCell is poor form, define it explicitly
4. Using `Range("A1").Value` is better but also poor form, fully define it like `workbooks("book1.xlsx").sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value`
5. You cant use the `letters.function(` type in vba, I've illustrated `instr` (or in string) to show how this can work to a similar effect.

I've changed your code to better illustrate what it maybe should look like:

```
Sub g()
    Dim subjectCell As String
    Dim letters As String
    Dim index As Integer

    letters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklçzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLÇZXCVBNM "
    'subjectCell = ActiveCell.Value
    subjectCell = "a"
    For i = 0 To Len(subjectCell) - 1

        If InStr(letters, subjectCell) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Found it!  It starts at position: " & InStr(letters, subjectCell)
        Else
            Debug.Print "No Match"
            index = i
        End If
    Next i

    Range("A1").Value = index
End Sub
```

Comment: Using `ActiveCell` like this is perfectly valid depending on how it's being called. OP may be linking this to a button and in which case it would be perfectly fine.